# Reading sas file from blob storage in R

Tags: azure-blob-storage, microsoft-r

I am trying to read .sas7bdat file from default container. I have tried following till now:

`sas_file <- RxSasData("wasbs://container@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/abc/xyz.sas7bdat")`

`sas_df <- rxImport(sas_file)`

but I get following error:

The file 'wasbs://container@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/abc/xyz.sas7bdat' does not exist.

Could not open data source.
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
  Could not open data source.

File exists at the mentioned location in code. Still it throws error. Can someone please help me this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, I think you want to local a SAS data file from HDFS on Azure HDInsight via `RxSasData`. However, `RxSasData` seems to be not supported on Hadoop env, as the figure below, please see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3104237/available-data-sources-for-distributed-compute-contexts).

[image]

Please try to copy the file to local filesystem on HDI, then to read.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. Link helped me lot.